# How do I know the total time I used to run workflow in github action?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions

Each time I create a PR or make commits, I have some workflows running. 
But since I have a private repo and I get only 2000 min/month for running workflows on Github Actions, I wanted to track the time used. How do I know how much total time I used out of 2000 free min that Github provides?

Is there a place in Github UI that you see the total time you used/ total time remaining?

Answer (score 10):

Once you are logged in to GitHub, you can view the GitHub actions minutes usage for your account at https://github.com/settings/billing under `GitHub Actions` as shown below

[image]

The above is documented in [GitHub help](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-billing-and-payments-on-github/viewing-your-github-actions-usage) too.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can get is the view in the main actions tab:

[image: behold my picture editing skills]

Sadly, no simple sum/month or anything like that was added as of yet.

The next best thing you could try is to whip up a script that collects these values from the page's dom for you.

Answer (score 0):

could use github cli to do this

```
createdAt=$(gh -R ${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}  run list \
  --json databaseId,createdAt --jq ".[]|select(.databaseId==${{ github.run_id }})|.createdAt")
usedSec=$(( `date +%s` - `date -d "$createdAt" +%s`  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was whether it is possible to get usage information per workflow from GitHub UI: no, it doesn't look like that's possible.

But you can install [GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/quickstart?apiVersion=2022-11-28#getting-started-using-github-cli) and get this information from their [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-workflow-usage) .e.g

```
gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" /repos/<owner>/<repo_name>/actions/workflows/<workflow_file_name>.yml/timing
```

It will present an output such as this:

```
{
  "billable": {
    "UBUNTU": {
      "total_ms": 17920000
    }
  }
}
```

As it's a REST API, you can also consume it in other ways, such as with `cURL`, of course. I found it faster to use to use the CLI (although it gave me some random "Server Error" sometimes).

Also found this GitHub Action, which was developed by a third party: [GitHub Actions Usage Audit](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-actions-usage-audit) Haven't tested it, though.