# What are github actions minutes/month?

Tags: github, github-actions

Can you please give a clear explanation, maybe with an example, as to what does `github` mean when saying that a plan includes `2000 actions minutes/month`? If I execute a `git pull` does this count as one action? How actions connect to minutes? The time I take to pull some commits from a repo counts towards the minutes I have?

I am aware of SO answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035886/how-do-i-know-the-total-time-i-used-to-run-workflow-in-github-action)) that may tell someone how to calculate the time remaining but I don't really understand what an action is.

For example, say I have a repository with some python/js code and I start working on a new system. When I do a `git pull` to clone my repository in this new system are there any actions in the backstage that are consumed? Do I consume any time from my plan? This is what I haven't clarified and needed maybe some simple examples to demonstrate. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know the total time I used to run workflow in github action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035886/how-do-i-know-the-total-time-i-used-to-run-workflow-in-github-action)

Comment: "Github Actions" has nothing to do with performing git operations on your repository

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I further edited the post to better describe my question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**GitHub Actions** is a [feature](https://github.com/features/actions) provided by GitHub to create workflows which can run on triggering any GitHub event, for eg run the build of the project on creation of a pull request. GitHub actions can be configured by creation of a workflow in the form of a yaml file and placing it under `.github/workflows` directory in your repo. [This](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/configuring-a-workflow) documentation provides more info regarding creating workflows.

> For example, say I have a repository with some python/js code and I start working on a new system. When I do a git pull to clone my repository in a new system are there any actions in the backstage that are consumed? Do I consume any time from my plan?

**No**, running a `git pull` to clone your repo **doesn't use up any allocated action minutes**.

GitHub actions only run if you have configured them to run by creating the workflows for specific GitHub events as mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#webhook-events). When any actions are configured for a repo, the same can be viewed under the `Actions` tab as shown below. Every GitHub action triggered shows up here.

[image]

Also, the current **2000 action minutes per month** allocation is for the triggered workflows for **private repos**, not public repos. You can check your usage of the free action minutes for private repos at https://github.com/settings/billing, as mentioned in my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035886/how-do-i-know-the-total-time-i-used-to-run-workflow-in-github-action/62729060#62729060) .

Comment: Any idea if 2,000 minutes per month is per repo or per account?

Comment: That's per account @Trevor. The reference is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/usage-limits-billing-and-administration#about-billing-for-github-actions).

Comment: As of 1 December 2021, the [products page](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/githubs-products) says GitHub Free for user accounts, as well as, organizations is limited to 2,000 GitHub Actions minutes (regardless of private/public repo)

Comment: @leanne GitHub Actions is free without any limit for public repositories. Please check out the [pricing page](https://github.com/features/actions#pricing-details) where it's mentioned "Free for public repositories" and [here](https://github.com/features/actions#pricing-details) too.

Comment: [Someone got an official confirmation](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/70492#discussioncomment-7362186) from Github Support that, **yes, *public* repos DO NOT have any minute limitations** *(October 2023)*

Answer (score 1):

That relates to [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), not things like pushing, pulling etc.