# How can I get the total build time of a GitHub action workflow?

Tags: github-actions

Is there any way to get the total build time of a GitHub action workflow? I did not find anything related to this in GitHub API and GraphQL.

Comment: Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035886/how-do-i-know-the-total-time-i-used-to-run-workflow-in-github-action). You can see total time in setting/billings -> usage this month -> github actions

Comment: Is there any API or GraphQL to fetch the same information? I am looking for workflow total time taken to complete not the billing time.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for appears to be in the github documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#get-workflow-run-usage)

Here's an example from that documentation

```
curl \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/actions/runs/42/timing
```

Note that the run number is not the sequentially generated number but what appears at the end of the url when you got to the instance of a run

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Get a workflow run service (Github API)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#get-a-workflow-run) to extract all datas from a specific workflow based on its `workflow_id`.

There is also a service to get [all workflow runs from a specific repository](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository).

Both will return a similar output (one on a list, and the other with a workflow object) similar to this one:

```json
{
  "id": 30433642,
  "name": "Build",
  "node_id": "MDEyOldvcmtmbG93IFJ1bjI2OTI4OQ==",
  "check_suite_id": 42,
  "check_suite_node_id": "MDEwOkNoZWNrU3VpdGU0Mg==",
  "head_branch": "master",
  "head_sha": "acb5820ced9479c074f688cc328bf03f341a511d",
  "run_number": 562,
  "event": "push",
  "status": "queued",
  "conclusion": null,
  "workflow_id": 159038,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642",
  "pull_requests": [],
  "created_at": "2020-01-22T19:33:08Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-01-22T19:33:08Z",
  "jobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/jobs",
  "logs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/logs",
  "check_suite_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/check-suites/414944374",
  "artifacts_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/artifacts",
  "cancel_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/cancel",
  "rerun_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/rerun",
  "workflow_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/workflows/159038",
  "head_commit": {
    "id": "acb5820ced9479c074f688cc328bf03f341a511d",
    "tree_id": "d23f6eedb1e1b9610bbc754ddb5197bfe7271223",
    "message": "Create linter.yaml",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-22T19:33:05Z",
    "author": {
      "name": "Octo Cat",
      "email": "octocat@github.com"
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "GitHub",
      "email": "noreply@github.com"
    }
  },
  "repository": {
    "id": 1296269,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMjk2MjY5",
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "hooks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks"
  },
  "head_repository": {
    "id": 217723378,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyMTc3MjMzNzg=",
    "name": "octo-repo",
    "full_name": "octo-org/octo-repo",
    "private": true,
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo",
    "description": null,
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/deployments"
  }
}
```

In this response, there are 2 fields - *`created_at` and `updated_at`* - that can be used to obtain the duration of the workflow execution.

As you'll see on the documentation, others services are available to get interesting datas about a workflow as well, such as [logs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#download-workflow-run-logs), [review history](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#get-the-review-history-for-a-workflow-run), [run usage (duration for each runner)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#get-workflow-run-usage) ...

Comment: Are you sure that `upadted_at` - `created_at` is always correct? I saw some weird behaviours where this calculated duration is another duration than displayed on the UI

Comment: We can't be sure of anything without working for GitHub directly :)

Comment: True :D
I found that `run_started_at` is present I think once the action is not scheduled anymore. So, I'm using that.

Thanks!