# Is there a variable in Github Actions that holds the total duration of a workflow run?

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to add to the Slack message that notifies that a Github workflow run has finished, the total duration it took to run.

Does anyone know how can it be achieved? I couldn't find "total duration" in any of the contexts...

Comment: What has been stated in this post could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67890631/how-can-i-get-the-total-build-time-of-a-github-action-workflow

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's available from a context, but you could do it with two separate `run` steps:

1. Store the current time as a timestamp (first step in workflow):

   ```yaml
   - name: Set start timestamp
     id: start
     run: |
       printf 'timestamp=%(%s)T\n' >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
   ```
2. Calculate difference (at end of workflow):

   ```yaml
   - name: Calculate duration
     run: |
       printf -v now '%(%s)T'
       duration=$((now - ${{ steps.start.outputs.timestamp }}))
       # Do something with duration, set as output to then use in Slack message
       # or similar
   ```

This puts the duration in seconds into the `duration` variable.